# Send a string array from controller to ASP.NET Core server side rendering JavaScript

Tags: asp.net-core, server-side-rendering, serverside-javascript, prerender, visual-studio-templates

Here's what I'm trying to achieve - I want to send a string array from my ASP.NET controller to the JavaScript (compiled from TypeScript) that's run both on server side (as prerendering) and on client side (as initial state). I'm using React-Redux template from Visual Studio.

My Controller method:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Services"] = new string[] { "ServiceA", "ServiceB" };
        return View();
    }
```

My cshtml view file:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";

    dynamic data = new
    {
        services = ViewData["Services"] as string[]
    };
}

<div id="react-app" asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server" asp-prerender-data=data>Loading...</div>

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/dist/main-client.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

My boot-server file portion:

```
return new Promise<RenderResult>((resolve, reject) => {
        actionCreators.addServices(params.data.services);
.......
```

My actionCrators object above is

```
export const actionCreators = {
    addServices: (services: string[]): AppThunkAction<KnownAction> => (dispatch, getState) => {

        dispatch({ type: 'ADD_SERVICES', services: services });
    }
};
```

which is mapped to this reducer:

```
const unloadedState: ServicesState = { services: [] };

export const reducer: Reducer<ServicesState> = (state: ServicesState, incomingAction: Action) => {
    const action = incomingAction as KnownAction;

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_SERVICES':
            return {
                services: action.services
            };
        default:
            // The following line guarantees that every action in the KnownAction union has been covered by a case above
            const exhaustiveCheck = action;
    }

    // For unrecognized actions (or in cases where actions have no effect), must return the existing state
    //  (or default initial state if none was supplied)
    return state || unloadedState;
};
```

If I set some values in the `unloadedState` array, the services array in initialState gets populated on server side and I can see them in view sources of my page. So my flux loop logic is fine. I'm suspecting the issue is passing string array from controller to `asp-prerender-data` via ViewData.

Please help.

Comment: Why didn't you just use a model and pass that to the view?

Comment: Because there isn't much to pass, I only want to pass a string array and model would be overkill I feel

Comment: Take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1#the-asp-prerender-data-tag-helper then look at what you are passing to the helper. My suggestion: try it manually first like shown in the example to prove it works and then that should give you an idea of  how you should pass it to the attribute.